# How to rotate an 3-D plot in Matplotlib around any axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, voxel, mplot3d

I am trying to rotate a 3D voxel plot generated in Matplotlib. Specifically, while retaining the coordinate system unchanged, I would like to rotate the image by 180 degrees about the x-axis. Here is an example from the Matplotlib documentation, and a visualization of the transformation I'd like to get with my plot:

[image: A visualization of rotation about the X-axis]

For reference, here is the code to generate the initial voxel plot (Also from the Matplotlib documentation):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def explode(data):
    size = np.array(data.shape)*2
    data_e = np.zeros(size - 1, dtype=data.dtype)
    data_e[::2, ::2, ::2] = data
    return data_e

# build up the numpy logo
n_voxels = np.zeros((4, 3, 4), dtype=bool)
n_voxels[0, 0, :] = True
n_voxels[-1, 0, :] = True
n_voxels[1, 0, 2] = True
n_voxels[2, 0, 1] = True
facecolors = np.where(n_voxels, '#FFD65DC0', '#7A88CCC0')
edgecolors = np.where(n_voxels, '#BFAB6E', '#7D84A6')
filled = np.ones(n_voxels.shape)

# upscale the above voxel image, leaving gaps
filled_2 = explode(filled)
fcolors_2 = explode(facecolors)
ecolors_2 = explode(edgecolors)

# Shrink the gaps
x, y, z = np.indices(np.array(filled_2.shape) + 1).astype(float) // 2
x[0::2, :, :] += 0.05
y[:, 0::2, :] += 0.05
z[:, :, 0::2] += 0.05
x[1::2, :, :] += 0.95
y[:, 1::2, :] += 0.95
z[:, :, 1::2] += 0.95

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.voxels(x, y, z, filled_2, facecolors=fcolors_2, edgecolors=ecolors_2)

plt.show()
```

For starters, I tried flipping the x-coordinates (using the `np.flip(x)` as an input to the x-coordinates; however, this distorts the light source, and does not yield the desired result. Any inputs on how to accomplish this rotation are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

```
def explode(data):
    size = np.array(data.shape)*2
    data_e = np.zeros(size - 1, dtype=data.dtype)
    data_e[::2, ::2, ::2] = data
    return data_e

# build up the numpy logo
n_voxels = np.zeros((4, 3, 4), dtype=bool)
n_voxels[0, 0, :] = True
n_voxels[-1, 0, :] = True
n_voxels[1, 0, 2] = True
n_voxels[2, 0, 1] = True
facecolors = np.where(n_voxels, '#FFD65DC0', '#7A88CCC0')
edgecolors = np.where(n_voxels, '#BFAB6E', '#7D84A6')
filled = np.ones(n_voxels.shape)

# upscale the above voxel image, leaving gaps
filled_2 = explode(filled)
fcolors_2 = explode(facecolors)
ecolors_2 = explode(edgecolors)

# Shrink the gaps
x, y, z = np.indices(np.array(filled_2.shape) + 1).astype(float) // 2
x[0::2, :, :] += 0.05
y[:, 0::2, :] += 0.05
z[:, :, 0::2] += 0.05
x[1::2, :, :] += 0.95
y[:, 1::2, :] += 0.95
z[:, :, 1::2] += 0.95

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def explode(data):
    size = np.array(data.shape)*2
    data_e = np.zeros(size - 1, dtype=data.dtype)
    data_e[::2, ::2, ::2] = data
    return data_e

# build up the numpy logo
n_voxels = np.zeros((4, 3, 4), dtype=bool)
n_voxels[0, 0, :] = True
n_voxels[-1, 0, :] = True
n_voxels[1, 0, 2] = True
n_voxels[2, 0, 1] = True
facecolors = np.where(n_voxels, '#FFD65DC0', '#7A88CCC0')
edgecolors = np.where(n_voxels, '#BFAB6E', '#7D84A6')
filled = np.ones(n_voxels.shape)

# upscale the above voxel image, leaving gaps
filled_2 = explode(filled)
fcolors_2 = explode(facecolors)
ecolors_2 = explode(edgecolors)

# Shrink the gaps
x, y, z = np.indices(np.array(filled_2.shape) + 1).astype(float) // 2
x[0::2, :, :] += 0.05
y[:, 0::2, :] += 0.05
z[:, :, 0::2] += 0.05
x[1::2, :, :] += 0.95
y[:, 1::2, :] += 0.95
z[:, :, 1::2] += 0.95

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.voxels(x, y, z, filled_2, facecolors=fcolors_2, edgecolors=ecolors_2)
for angle in range(0, 360):
    ax.view_init(30, angle)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.001)
    
plt.show()
```